# Building an index as dep. for regression

Tags: regression, ranking

I have two dependent variables: the health and the environmental impact of individuals’ diets. Both variables are continuous but on different scales/ranges. For both high values/impacts are bad. I want to merge the two towards an index depicting healthy and sustainable eating patterns, and then to run regression on the index variable to explore the aspects that fosters/hinders healthy & sustainable eating.I see a few options for this:

- sum the z-values of both variables and divide by 2, then run OLS linear regression
- sum the z-values of both variables and divide by 2, compute the ranks for Healthy&Sust. eating, then run ordered logistic regressions
- compute ranks for both – sum up in a new variable and compute rank orders again -> perform ordered logistic regression.

Maybe somebody has a good argument in favor of one of the propositions, or even any better?
Many thanks, Ivo

Comment: A strong argument against any of the above is that they are all arbitrary.  Have you considered a multivariate analysis or two separate analyses of each dependent variable?

Comment: thanks. Yes I did perform multivariate regression on the two dependent variables. However, I am also interested in looking at the two variables combined, as an additional step. I do not fully understand why this should be so arbitrary.  It see its as if I want to explain performance in 100m sprint and wide-jump, but then I am also interested in the "cross-product" of the two.